# Google analytics referrals from strange sites

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

My google analytics page shows a few referrals from

```
adtiger.tk
getrichquick.ml
```

I'm not a "ProWebmaster" - just administering a small site hosted by my university. My newbie question: do I need to worry about this?

If the answer is "yes" I can probably manage to implement this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666318/how-to-block-spam-referrers-like-darodar-com-from-accessing-website/28354319#28354319

Comment: It is an annoyance more than anything. It is recommended that you filter the various referral spam found in GA if you want to use it for actionable detail. There is no problem leaving it, technically, except that it is bogus data. For the record, we have been yelling that Google should be more cooperative by detecting and removing this data automatically. It is fine if it takes a while to detect. Just remove it. It is junk data that does no-one any good at all. Otherwise, the spammers win and we lose. That, to me, is far more frustrating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrre is no need to worry about this as it does not affect your server at all it only affects Google Analytics. If your interested in knowing how it has been done you can see details on it at http://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/12/19/darodar-com-referrer-spam/

This is an attack on Google Analytics and to try and trick webmasters into visiting the site by inserting fake referals into your GA logs. If you double check your server logs and applucation logs you will see no actual referred connections from darodar.com or the associated IP addresses.